# Extjs Type error undefined is not an object(evaluating 'data["id"]')

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, model, sencha-architect

[image: Error]
Am getting the above error while creating a page. I have set 'idProperty' config for all models and is unique.  This error occures in ipad only. I cannot explain the scenario how this error occurs as this not coming every time.

Can any body experienced this type of errors. I am stuck at this.

Thanks,

Anish.

Comment: We need additional information on this question, code example or a fiddle would be great. It obviously an issue that's going to be difficult to find, even with the code. Without being able to replicate the issue and play around with it this question will be difficult to answer.

Comment: Agree with @Scriptable we're going to need quite a lot more info and ideally a reproducible fiddle here.